# Constants in the expression tree generated by entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#potential-memory-leak-in-client-evaluation) mentions that:

> EF Core generates parameters for the client-evaluated parts of the tree and reuses the query plan by replacing the parameter values. But certain constants in the expression tree can't be converted into parameters.

Why does the doc emphasize on constants and for example not on 'normal' (mutable) field of some class ?
What exactly is meant by constant in this context?

**Update**

Some example without direct connection to EF:

```
class Color
{
    private AppDBConext _context = new();
    public string defaultValue = "green";
}

class Background
{
    private static Func<string, Color, string> CreateGetColorFunc()
    {
        Expression<Func<string, Color, string>> expression = (color, shade) => color.defaultValue + "-" + shade;
        var rVal = expression.Compile();
        return rVal;
    }
}
```

Can `color` and `shade` be considered as constants?

Comment: Constant as far as the query execution is concerned, as opposed to something relevant to a certain row in the data being queried.

Comment: These are explained in the *"Common causes and their solutions"* section of the EF Core documentation link in the question.

Comment: I added example in question because I am a little bit confused with term `constant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can color and shade be considered as constants?

It is wrong sample for EF Core.

Constants here means that services, classes, etc. used in `Select(x => new {...})` can be treated as constant value and will be cached with translated query, which may introduce potential memory leak and undefined behaviour.

As parameters EF Core can use local variables and expressions which EF Core can evaluate during translation. Whole expression is marked as parameter and special value retrieval function is generated.

The following query can cache `this` reference as constant

```cs
query.Select(x => this.SomeMethod(123, x.SomeProp))
```

After entering method which executes the same query second time, `this` will be used from previous execution - probably not what you expect.

*I can explain in more details but I need to understand how deep do you want to know how LINQ Translator works.*

Comment: > Constants here means that services, classes, etc. used in Select(x => new {...}) can be treated as constant

Does this mean that object `c` of class 'Color' will be treated the same as `1` or `2` in `Expression<Func<int>> sum = () => 1 + 2;`
Is there any docs that describes the process of treating in more detail and describe terminology (constants etc)?

Comment: Are you solving some concrete issue or just polish documentation understanding? I'm not native English speaker and polemic is not my best side. And you again shown lambda which is not suitable here. No additional books, no documentation, only EF Core source code.

Comment: I tried to solve another issue about join in EF, but encountered this doc and this question came up to me. Thank you for the answer. I edited my profile, so you can contact me to discuss it in more detail in native language.

Comment: `Join` is not related to this documentation section. If you have problem with `Join`, create new question and explain problem.

Comment: I simply wanted to mention how this question appeared:) I solved problem with join, but while searching, I encountered this doc.